# Airflow not render timedelta parameter

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to pass a `timedelta(hours=2)` as a parameter to a `DAG` as one of the `default_args`. I read in some params from a config file as this: `config = {'name': 'task1', 'freq': 'Daily', 'timeout': 'timedelta(hours=2)' }`

Then I tried to pass this into a `default_args`, but seeing from the dag details, airflow did not recognise it. What did I do wrong here? Many thanks for your help.

```
timeout = config["timeout"]
default_args ={
     "retries" =0,
     "execution_timeout" = timeout
  }
```

Comment: what exactly is config? are you referring to the dict you pass when you trigger DAG manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to take the DAG args from a config file since you can have some weird behavior in Airflow. To your question, you have the string of a function and to accomplish what you need you can use [`eval()`](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/).

Try this (I refactored your code since it doesn't work as it is):

```py
timeout = config["timeout"]
default_args = {
    "retries": 0,
    "execution_timeout": eval(timeout),
}
```